# Why is my AWS Deployed Spring Boot REST API only allowing POST requests in AWS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I have a very simple Spring Boot REST API that creates, reads, updates and destroys Users. I set up RDS with MySQL as the database and deployed the Spring Boot app with Elastic Beanstalk.

Everything seemed great at first; however, when I test my API using Postman, I am only able to create Users by making a POST request. Every other endpoint I get a 500 status: internal server error.

I go to my Elastic Beanstalk environment and I see that I am getting a warning saying "Environment health has transitioned from OK to Severe. 100.0 % of the requests are failing with HTTP 5xx."

I check MySQL Workbench and the entries were saved I just can't do a GET, PUT, or DELETE request without getting a 500 error. I am so stuck right now. I tested the REST API on Postman on local host before deploying to AWS and it worked just fine.

I am new to AWS services and this is my first time trying to deploy my REST API so I am not even sure where to go from here. Is this an issue with my code or with the way I configured Elastic Beanstalk or RDS?

***EDIT***
I am adding the code for my UserController here to see if maybe I messed up something there and I just can't see it.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    // get all users
    @GetMapping
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return this.userRepository.findAll();
    }

    // get user by id
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public User getUserById(@PathVariable(value = "id") long userId) {
        return this.userRepository.findById(userId).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User not found with ID: " + userId));
    }

    // create user

    @PostMapping
    public User createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        return this.userRepository.save(user);
    }

    // update user

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public User updateUser(@RequestBody User user, @PathVariable("id") long userId) {
        User existingUser = this.userRepository.findById(userId).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User not found with ID: " + userId));
        existingUser.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
        existingUser.setLastName(user.getLastName());
        existingUser.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        return this.userRepository.save(existingUser);
    }
    // delete user by id

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") long userId) {
        User existingUser = this.userRepository.findById(userId).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User not found with ID: " + userId));
        this.userRepository.delete(existingUser);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

I would also like to add that when I first tested my GET request endpoint I got a status 200 and got an empty array (the database was empty). I then tested the POST request and then went to test the GET request again and got a status 500.

Comment: did you look at the log file to see what the error is?

Comment: You should show your code that you use in your Controller.. As explained in my answer, once you setup your Spring BOOT project properly on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, you can perform GET, POST, PUT requests.

Comment: I checked the log file but I didn't see any errors. ??? I don't know maybe I am looking in the wrong spot? I have updated the post with my Controller as well!

Answer (score 1):

We have an example of creating a Rest API using a Spring BOOT project that uses an Amazon RDS data client to perform CRUD operations on an Amazon Aurora Serverless database. That is, this example shows how to develop a Spring REST API that queries Amazon Aurora Serverless data.

The Spring REST API uses the AWS SDK for Java (v2) to invoke AWS services and is used by a React application that displays the data.

The use case:

1 - A React app invokes a Rest API created using a Spring Boot project.

2 - The Spring Boot app that performs **RDS CRUD operations** can be deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk and it works perfectly.

3 - I can perform GET/PUT/POST requests from Postman to my Spring BOOT Rest API deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, as shown here (this image shows a result set from an RDS database by performing a **GET** request). This is the same REST API created by following the HOW TO article listed below.

[image]

Now the React app is able to perform a GET/POST request, get back data and display the data.

[image]

Here is link to the doc that walks you through building a Spring BOOT REST API and a React front end. This is very close to your use case. (this example uses Aurora vs your use case of MySQL).

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/Creating_Spring_RDS_%20Rest

This example does not describe how to deploy to the AWS Elastic Beanstalk (the last link in my answer does). When you deploy a Spring Boot app that interacts with an RDS database on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk, you need to define inbound rules to successfully perform CRUD operations on the database.

To handle inbound rules, you can configure your App on AWS Elastic Beanstalk to use the same security group as the RDS database. More information here in the AWS Doc:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html

You can set this by clicking the Configuration option in AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

[image]

Set your other options for a Spring BOOT app too such as Server Port to 5000 and so on. Once you do all of this, your Restful API will be able to accept POST, PUT, and GET requests and get data from an RDS instance.

Last reference that can help you. As you are new, here is another doc that talks about **how to deploy a Spring BOOT APP to AWS Elastic Beanstalk**. Note the settings you need to set at the end of this doc.

[Creating your first AWS Java web application](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/creating_first_project)